# Filling in NULLS with previous records - Netezza SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hql

I am using Netezza SQL on Aginity Workbench and have the following data:

```
id           DATE1              DATE2
1            2013-07-27         NULL
2            NULL               NULL
3            NULL               2013-08-02
4            2013-09-10         2013-09-23
5            2013-12-11         NULL
6            NULL               2013-12-19
```

I need to fill in all the NULL values in DATE1 with preceding values in the DATE1 field that are filled in. With DATE2, I need to do the same, but in reverse order. So my desired output would be the following:

```
id           DATE1              DATE2
1            2013-07-27         2013-08-02
2            2013-07-27         2013-08-02
3            2013-07-27         2013-08-02
4            2013-09-10         2013-09-23
5            2013-12-11         2013-12-19
6            2013-12-11         2013-12-19
```

I only have read access to the data. So creating Tables or views are out of the question

Comment: Is there any sort of id column establishing the order? Given that you want row 2 (which only contains nulls, from the columns you provided) to clearly be in between row 1 and row 3, there must be at least one other column that can make that determinable. Database tables are not ordered sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [this](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_first_last_family_syntax.html)?

```
select
  id
  ,last_value(date1 ignore nulls) over (
    order by id
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ) date1
  ,first_value(date2 ignore nulls) over (
    order by id
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ) date2
```

You can manually calculate this as well, rather than relying on the windowing functions.

```
with chain as (
  select 
    this.*,
    prev.date1 prev_date1,
    case when prev.date1 is not null then abs(this.id - prev.id) else null end prev_distance,
    next.date2 next_date2,
    case when next.date2 is not null then abs(this.id - next.id) else null end next_distance
  from 
    Table1 this 
    left outer join Table1 prev on this.id >= prev.id
    left outer join Table1 next on this.id <= next.id
), min_distance as (
  select
    id,
    min(prev_distance) min_prev_distance,
    min(next_distance) min_next_distance
  from
    chain
  group by
    id
)
select
  chain.id,
  chain.prev_date1,
  chain.next_date2
from
  chain
  join min_distance on 
    min_distance.id = chain.id
    and chain.prev_distance = min_distance.min_prev_distance
    and chain.next_distance = min_distance.min_next_distance
order by chain.id
```

If you're unable to calculate the distance between IDs by subtraction, just replace the ordering scheme by a `row_number()` call.

Comment: While the self join answer provided by @FuzzyTree will produce the same results,I think you will find that  the window aggregate solution provided here by jeremytwfortune may be orders of magnitude faster as it involves only one snippet, and relies on no expression based joins which will cause broadcasts of the table.  On the other hand, the window aggregate relies more on host processing because there is no PARTITION BY clause. Give them both a try, and see which works faster for you.  If I were a betting man, I'd go with Jeremy's.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottMcG. I'm not entirely sure that the solution by @FuzzyTree actually does give the same answer, though. If you edit ID 3 to have a date lower than ID 1, the date from ID 1 appears on the line for ID 3. This is because the aggregate used is `min` and `max`, not `first_value` and `last_value`.

Comment: Doh! I was lazy looking at that one.

Comment: @ScottMcG - this window agg  gives `ERROR:  614057 : Partition rowcount limit exceeded` in my case on Netezza with a table of 4 million rows, with smaller test data it works fine - any ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer to remove window functions if your data is too large to use them.

Comment: @JeremyFortune - this works for small datasets, thanks !! I ran this with different number of records and with increasing time it ran till 100K records, but with 1million records it gave error.                                  `1,000 recs, 1.0 secs`
`10,000 recs, 1.6 secs`
`100,000 recs, 114.5 secs`
`1,000,000 recs, 2105.8 secs , Error - ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  SPU swap partition : Disk temporary work space is full`

Comment: Well, yeah. At 1 million records, the `chain` subquery will be ~ 2.5 * 10^17 records. If you can guarantee that the next most recent non-null date items occur within a certain distance of the `id`, try restricting the `chain` join to be between two distances (`this.id between prev.id and prev.id - 10`). If you can't, then an iterative solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I think Netezza supports the `order by` clause for `max()` and `min()`.  So, you can do:

```
select max(date1) over (order by date1) as date1,
       min(date2) over (order by date2 desc) as date2
 . . .
```

EDIT:

In Netezza, you may be able to do this with `last_value()` and `first_value()`:

```
select last_value(date1 ignore nulls) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as date1,
       first_value(date1 ignore nulls) over (order by id rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as date2
```

Netezza doesn't seem to support `IGNORE NULL`s on `LAG()`, but it does on these functions.

Comment: Just tried that - it doesn't entirely solve my issue. You'll see in the example that when there is a new value for Date1, I want the NULLs after it to take on that new value. While if we used min() over() or even first_value() over(), it would fill in the nulls with the global minimum...Thanks for the answer though...I updated my question to make it more clear what I want

Answer (score 0):

I've only tested this in Oracle so hopefully it works in Netezza:

**Fiddle:**
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7533f/1/0

```
select id,
       coalesce(date1, t1_date1, t2_date1) as date1,
       coalesce(date2, t3_date2, t4_date2) as date2
  from (select t.*,
               t1.date1 as t1_date1,
               t2.date1 as t2_date1,
               t3.date2 as t3_date2,
               t4.date2 as t4_date2,
               row_number() over(partition by t.id order by t.id) as rn
          from tbl t
          left join tbl t1
            on t1.id < t.id
           and t1.date1 is not null
          left join tbl t2
            on t2.id > t.id
           and t2.date1 is not null
          left join tbl t3
            on t3.id < t.id
           and t3.date2 is not null
          left join tbl t4
            on t4.id > t.id
           and t4.date2 is not null
         order by t.id) x
 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to fill in `NULL` dates with the most recent min/max non-null dates using self-joins. This query should work on most databases

```
select t1.id, max(t2.date1), min(t3.date2)
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
join tbl t3 on t1.id <= t3.id
group by t1.id
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/acc997/2